# Nginx proxy manager forward to folder

Tags: networking, proxy, nginx

I am trying to setup [azuracast](https://www.azuracast.com/)behind [nginx proxy manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/)

Specifically my stations "public channel" *not* my management page. The way azuracast works on the local network is http://x.x.x.x:xxxx forwards to http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/dashboard automatically.

The public channel I want to expose through nginx proxy manager is at http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/public/stationName

I cannot seem to figure out how to make that work. Nginx reverse proxy manager's UI has a section "custom location" when entering a proxy host, but that page ALSO asks for scheme, ip and port which doesn't sound what I want since thats already entered.

I tried https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager/issues/104#issuecomment-490720849 but that also did not work.

I am using nginx reverse proxy to host a couple other things behind the same IP, so would like to use it for this too. Is it possible?

EDIT:

I have this a little further along, and can get the page to load now after reading [This Comment](https://github.com/jc21/nginx-proxy-manager/issues/671#issuecomment-721198949) and adding:

location = /{return 301 $scheme://$http_host/public/stationName/;}

to "custom nginx configuration" under advanced in nginx proxy manager.

The public page loads, I can see the station and progress bar for the playing son, but media seems to be blocked. No sound or album art. Getting a Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG when trying to load the album art at least, no idea about sound.